# With Paperclip, how could I create a attachment object using a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Basically, because Omniauth retrieves URL's of the user's profile picture for say, Facebook, I need to find a way to generate attach that URL as a file for the user.

Comment: A good read [here](http://trevorturk.com/2008/12/11/easy-upload-via-url-with-paperclip/).